# About task onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a class AsyncTask that worked well, but in this class I have a ProgressDialog in the onPreExecute, that worked ok, but I need that when I finish the process the processdialog close, I put the code in the onPostExecute, this way:

```
protected void onPostExecute() {
    progress.dismiss();
}
```

But it doesn't do anything. The dialog doesn't dismiss.
This is the all code:

```
public class JsonRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

private final Context context;
private ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
private ProgressDialog progress;

public JsonRequest(Context c){
    this.context = c;
}

protected void onPreExecute(){
    progress= new ProgressDialog(this.context);
    progress.setMessage("Loading");
    progress.show();
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {

        final String POST_PARAMS = params[1];

        URL obj = new URL(params[0]);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

        // For POST only - START
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        // For POST only - END

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            JSONArray myListsAll= new JSONArray(response.toString());
            for(int i=0;i<myListsAll.length();i++){

                JSONObject jsonObject = myListsAll.getJSONObject(i);
                this.stringArray.add(jsonObject.toString());
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("POST request not worked");
        }


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return this.stringArray;
}

protected void onPostExecute() {
    progress.dismiss();
}
```

So I call:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    private void createListView() {
        itens = new ArrayList<ItemFeedsListView>();

        String[] itensUrl = {"url","data"};
        JsonRequest task = new JsonRequest(this);
        try {
            ArrayList<String> result = task.execute(itensUrl).get();

            for(int i = 0 ; i < result.size() ; i++) {
                String currentList = result.get(i);
                JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(currentList);

                ItemFeedsListView item = new ItemFeedsListView(jsonobject.optString("value1"),jsonobject.optString("value2"),jsonobject.optString("valeu3"),jsonobject.optString("value4"),jsonobject.optString("value5"), R.mipmap.eu, R.mipmap.logo);
                itens.add(item);

            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Cria o adapter
        adapterListView = new AdapterFeedsListView(this, itens);

        //Define o Adapter
        listView.setAdapter(adapterListView);
        //Cor quando a lista é selecionada para ralagem.
        listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling the right onPostExecute:

You need:

```
@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> data) {
    super.onPostExecute(data);
    progress.dismiss();
}
```

The problem is your not overriding the method in AsyncTask class just by adding an `onPostExecute()`. you need to Add @Override annotation and pass in the return type of your AsyncTask Class.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using AsyncTask correctly.  Look at this line of code:

```
ArrayList<String> result = task.execute(itensUrl).get();
```

What this is doing is starting an AsyncTask (which would normally do the bulk of its work in a background thread), and then *immediately* blocking the main thread to receive its result using the get() method.  You might as well not even use an AsyncTask in this case because the point of an AsyncTask is to free the main thread from having to do lengthy operations.

Instead, you should be acting on the work done from the background thread in your onPostExecute() alone.

Comment: Hello Doug, You are right, using this way the uithread was blocked, how this topic was created to fix the error about the process loading that the inner_class7 show to resolve, I changed my code like you suggested and created other topic to talk about. I would like that you put there your opinion. Thanks Thanks This is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685688/suggestion-about-asynctask

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the visibility by this way:

```
@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> data) {
    super.onPostExecute(data);
    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```