# Suggestion about AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

In this topic:
[About task onPostExecute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35637463/about-task-onpostexecute)

I asked about onPostExecute to dismiss a process, the friend @inner_class7 give me the way to resolve the error, but the friend @Doug Stevenson said that using this way the code will blocking the uithread, I tested and this is true, my uithraed was blocked. So He said that I need to use onPostExecute to get the result. I read about and created a code and I would like suggestion about.
I changed the code and do it:

```
protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {

        final String POST_PARAMS = params[1];

        URL obj = new URL(params[0]);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

        // For POST only - START
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        // For POST only - END

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            // print result
            System.out.println(response.toString());



            JSONArray myListsAll= new JSONArray(response.toString());
            for(int i=0;i<myListsAll.length();i++){

                JSONObject jsonObject = myListsAll.getJSONObject(i);
                this.stringArray.add(jsonObject.toString());
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("POST request not worked");
        }


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return this.stringArray;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result)
{
   this.obj.setFeedsData(result);
    if(setProgress){ progress.dismiss(); }
}
```

So call in my mainactivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     String[] itensUrl = {links.feedsList(),"iduser=2&offset=0"};
    new JsonRequest(this,this,true).execute(itensUrl);
}

public void setFeedsData(ArrayList<String> obj){
    createListView(obj);
}
```

So what Do you think about? This way that a use is a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should be working just fine. You are correctly executing and parsing the results of the request off the UI thread. However, there are a couple minor things you can do to make it clearer.

`stringArray` looks like a field on the `AsyncTask`. This is not necessary the way you have the `AsyncTask` defined since you are already passing the `stringArray` directly into the `onPostExecute()` method. You should instead declare `stringArray` directly in the `doInBackground()` method.

Other thing I noticed is it looks like you might be keeping a reference to your `Activity` in the `AsyncTask` based on what you are doing in `onPostExecute()`. You are calling `this.obj.setFeedsData(result);`. If your `AsyncTask` is an inner class of the `Activity` using it you can call `setFeedsData(result);` directly instead.

If your `AsyncTask` is not an inner class it is usually best to pass the results back to the object interested in them through an interface in case you need to reuse the `AsyncTask` elsewhere.

Comment: Good, Thanks to the suggestion, You are right, I changed my code to your suggestion